# What does “particular enumeration” mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The other, showing the mass graves covered over with earth and marked by placards, evokes, in the barrenness and vastness of the graves, the totality of the Nazi crimes that, somehow, seem to surpass their **particular enumeration**. [Source](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/movies/2014/01/hitchcock-and-the-holocaust.html)

What does the author want to say here with this *particular enumeration*?

Answer (score 1):

Enumeration is the fact of having counted (given a number to) something. So what the author is saying is that the sight of the huge, mass graves impressed upon him the reality of the Holocaust more vividly than simply reading the number of victims, or any other list of German crimes.

Comment: I think you mean "Enumeration is the **act** of counting or giving a number to something."